# Adding a line break to php Fwrite output

Tags: php, html, fopen, fwrite, fclose

Basically, I was trying to find a simple piece of code for a simple note taking thing in html, I want to type in an html input form, then that input be added on to a text file i found this,

```
<h1>Adding a text block to a text file:</h1>
<form action="index.php" method='post'>
<textarea name='textblock'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Add text'>
</form>

<?php

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("text.html", "a");

// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"]); 

// Close the text file
fclose($f);

// Open file for reading, and read the line
$f = fopen("text.html", "r");

// Read text
echo fgets($f); 
fclose($f);

?>
```

Which works, but needs line breaks at the end of the output, such as if i wrote "test" and then "test" again, it outputs as "testtest" obviously, but I want two line breaks between them, like

"Test

Test"

I also want to add another input called "Subject" which will be the subject of the note,I'm open to any suggestions, if this code is wrong, or over complicated, then feel free to shorten it or just give me a entirely new one.

Thanks for any help

Terry.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php

Comment: use fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"].PHP_EOL);

Comment: Just put this $_POST["textblock"] . '\r\n'

Answer (score 1):

PHP_EOL is a predefined constant in PHP since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2. See the manual posting:

Using this will save you extra coding on cross platform developments.

IE.

```
$data = 'some data'.PHP_EOL;
$fp = fopen('somefile', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

If you looped through this twice you would see in 'somefile':

```
some data
some data
```

Answer (score 0):

in html you need to use `<br />` .
But your form probably writes `\n` in the database.
use nl2br() for that:

```
$htmltext = nl2br($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out !

```
<h1>Adding a text block to a text file:</h1>
<form action="index.php" method='post'>
<textarea name='textblock'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Add text'>
</form><?php

if(isset($_POST["textblock"]))
{
    $myFile='text.html';
    file_put_contents($myFile,$_POST["textblock"]."<br>",FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
    echo file_get_contents($myFile);
}

?>
```